# Force HTAccess to give a slash in end and parse the php GET values

Tags: php, .htaccess, root, redirect

I have domain arranged like this

```
localhost/editor/index.php   // This is the php file which require get variables
localhost/editor/.htaccess   // htaccess file which will pass values to index.php
```

HTAccess file : code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ index.php?u=$1&e=$2
```

I want to make url like this

```
localhost/editor/variable1/variable2/
```

after this if someone will miss a slash at end he will get object not found error
I have tried different ways  but i am unable to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code instead

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /editor/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?u=$1&e=$2 [L]
```

This way, you can access

```
localhost/editor/variable1/variable2
```

or

```
localhost/editor/variable1/variable2/
```

But i recommend you to choose one and to disallow the other one (to avoid duplicate content)